# How to draw a vertical bar chart in oxyplot (latest source code version)?

Tags: c#, oxyplot

This produces a horizontal bar chart. How do I get a vertical bar chart?

**Important** I am using the latest soure code version, i.e. I checked out the latest source code from https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot and built oxyplot myself (the ColumnSeries is gone and replaced with BarSeries).

```
var plotModel = new PlotModel { Title = "An Example Chart with 1 Bar Series",
                                Background = OxyColors.White };

var barSeries = new BarSeries();
barSeries.IsStacked = false;
plotModel.Series.Add(barSeries);

barSeries.Items.Add(new BarItem(0));
barSeries.Items.Add(new BarItem(18));
barSeries.Items.Add(new BarItem(12));
barSeries.Items.Add(new BarItem(8));
barSeries.Items.Add(new BarItem(15));

return plotModel;
```

Here a picture

[horizontal bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK8w3.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is `LinearBarSeries` class in `OxyPlot`, unfortunately `BarWidth` expressed in pixels and doesn't scale on resize. This class is not designed well for extension - render function calls private methods and use private fields, `GetBarWidth` is not virtual, so only reasonable way to alter behaviour is to copy-paste everything and change relevant parts and mimic `BarSeries.Items` property (optionally).
Code here: [https://github.com/mugiseyebrows/VerticalBarChart/](https://github.com/mugiseyebrows/VerticalBarChart/blob/master/VerticalBarChart/StretchyLinearBarSeries.cs)